# OmniAuth using wrong callback port in a reverse proxy setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, port, omniauth, reverse-proxy

I have a Rails app running on port `3101` and I made it available to the internet through an Apache reverse-proxy setup (like the one suggested by Phusion on [this blog post](http://blog.phusion.nl/2010/09/21/phusion-passenger-running-multiple-ruby-versions/).

I'm using Devise + OmniAuth to handle the Facebook authentication.

But when I try to authenticate via Facebook, I'm redirected to the url: `http://mydomain.com:3101/my_callback_path`

I start the rails app with `passenger start -a 127.0.0.1 -p 3101 -d` and my Apache setup is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.com

    PassengerEnabled off
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3101/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3101

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

I've found some answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206616/changing-callback-uri-of-omniauth-in-rails) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590855/tricking-a-rails-app-to-think-its-on-a-different-port/6115762#6115762) but they all are intended to Nginx setups.

I've tried to use an initializer with `OmniAuth.config.full_host = 'http://my domain.com'` but  I'm  wondering if there`s not a missing configuration in my apache setup (like the previous answers).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had a look into the OmniAuth source and found out that the callback mechanism internally uses a method named `full_host` that looks up the configuration variable and then builds the first part of the URI - have a look at `oa-core-0.2.6/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb`

The configuration variable can be a String (as in your case), or a Proc, or nil (or anything else). In the latter case, the request URI is parsed, chopped, and returned.

I think that we can't solve our common problem by just setting an environment variable in Apache (this probably should be done at a lower level, inside the ruby application stack), but after some experimentation I've found this works well enough for me:

```
OmniAuth.config.full_host = lambda do |env|
    scheme         = env['rack.url_scheme']
    local_host     = env['HTTP_HOST']
    forwarded_host = env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST']
    forwarded_host.blank? ? "#{scheme}://#{local_host}" : "#{scheme}://#{forwarded_host}"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It was solved by setting

```
**proxy_set_header        Host            <proxy-domain-name>;**



  location / {
  proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header        Host            <domain name>;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 }
```

Regarding facebook redirect issue, I spent some time investigating the value of the actual url it was redirecting the callback to, so I had to fix that in nginx conf. For finding that out, look at the url in the link and see the value of "redirect_uri" GET variable value instead of focusing on the error it sent on the main page.